# How can I start cruising around in another city, without doing job?

Tags: american-truck-simulator

Pls see the four screenshots under. I'm using Mods and the [Everything Unlocked v1.1.1 1.34.x profile](https://atsmod.net/american-truck-simulator-mods/ats-partstuning/everything-unlocked-v1-1-1-1-34-x/) - it picked Las Vegas, not me. I'm too busy with work to unlock everything.

I don't know why Porsche is  in LV. I just want start driving in Porsche in Oregon, not do any jobs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After I clicked "Yes", game automatically loaded the drive.

[image]

As you can see this last screen-shot, why is Porsche still in LV???

Comment: It has been a while since I played, but are you unable to free roam at all?

Comment: @LoreFriendly what buttons do i click to free roam?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: Just re-examined your screenshots.**

***You've switched to the FORD F-150***

Assuming the issue isn't with the ability to *Free Roam*, but that you can't seem to switch locations:

Set the driver for the Porsche as yourself again.

Then, if still not in Portland, use the *[Quick Travel](https://guides.gamepressure.com/americantrucksimulator/guide.asp?ID=33719)* feature to go to your garage in Portland.

[image]

If this still doesn't work perhaps there's something at work in the mods affecting the gameplay? (although this seems unlikely)

Comment: hi. thanks. yes. i'm running mods. i updated my post. want to update your last sentence too?

Comment: @DongmeiMayWang Is the quick travel option not there on the garages list screen?